# Android Studio SDK issue

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I wanted to try the new Android Studio, but when i start it i get this error

```
    null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.getStyle(ResourceResolver.java:574)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.computeStyleInheritance(ResourceResolver.java:503)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.computeStyleMaps(ResourceResolver.java:462)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.create(ResourceResolver.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.Configuration.getResourceResolver(Configuration.java:1059)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidColorAnnotator.annotateResourceReference(AndroidColorAnnotator.java:193)
    at org.jetbrains.android.AndroidColorAnnotator.annotate(AndroidColorAnnotator.java:101)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.runAnnotators(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:160)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.visit(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:103)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$11.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:650)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:763)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$3500(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$13.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:769)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DefaultHighlightVisitor.analyze(DefaultHighlightVisitor.java:87)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:766)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.access$3500(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass$13.run(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:769)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.RefCountHolder.analyze(RefCountHolder.java:295)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.analysis.HighlightVisitorImpl.analyze(HighlightVisitorImpl.java:139)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.analyzeByVisitors(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:766)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectHighlights(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:723)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.GeneralHighlightingPass.collectInformationWithProgress(GeneralHighlightingPass.java:214)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:58)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:62)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1196)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass$1.run(PassExecutorService.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:226)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:345)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:321)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$3.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:145)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$3.call(JobLauncherImpl.java:142)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.access$101(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:31)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask$1.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:70)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.PrioritizedFutureTask.run(PrioritizedFutureTask.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When i click on SDK manager or AVD Manager i get a "Please specify Android SDK" error
I tried to specify in the Project structure the SDK (updated to the latest) i was using in Eclipse but still the same error.
Do you know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the solution, Go in File>Project Structure
In the Project tab locate project SDK and set it to android sdk

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! I had android sdk set before, but I had to hit  "edit" and set up build target in SDKs tab.

Comment: This should be set ans answered

Comment: I couldn't find this option in 2.3.3